# Puzzling Introduction suggestion - Spoilers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support

*I apologize in advance if this post is bias towards an opinion as I have not thoroughly analyzed it. I am open to suggestions if something sounds too bias, brash or naive [if it shouldn't be].*

I have found this issue arising quite frequently and I don't know if there are currently solutions in helping to reduce it:

Situation:

A new member joins the Puzzling community (possibly fresh or active from another SE). Then they post their first question or answer and it doesn't have proper spoiler tags or formatting! I have found myself having to explain how to use spoiler tags and some other features multiple times. (I myself initially didn't know until explained to). I have noticed a similar situation in markup questions from the meta post [here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3048/11244)

Considering that on Puzzling, knowing the basics of using single/multi-line spoiler tags are very frequently used, I feel that making this information more formally introduced or available to (new) members could help in reducing many post edits/explinations. [Similarly to how tags are introduced]

I have looked over the tour page and have been unable to find anything related to this, and it seems that this information could be useful for many other users. (i.e I still don't fully know how to implement math properly and have only used it from other answers)

Are there other methods to learning about this? Do you think this is significant enough to introduce to new/existing users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a page in the help center that demonstrates all the markup: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help. If you see a new user who doesn't know how to properly format their posts, you can comment underneath with this link.

To refer a user specifically to the spoilers part, use https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers. The markdown help for spoilers will appear at the top.

Comment: I noticed that there is no mention of spoiler tags on this page?

Comment: Oops, wrong link. It's at the bottom of this one.

Comment: Well, if you want to refer someone specifically to the spoilers part, you can do http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers. Then it will appear at the top of the page.

Comment: The introduction to spoilers is rather limited. It doesn't show how to embed multiple paragraphs, images, code, or lists in spoilers.

Comment: @xnor Is it really necessary to include all of these things? Basically that is just using two of the formatting, for example, using the correct markdown for images then putting it in spoiler tags. Using a little bit of logic to determine the correct order isn't so hard.

Comment: @mmking Well, when I first did it, I didn't know about putting two spaces afterwards to start a new paragraph, so everything in the spoiler became all smushed together.

Comment: @xnor True, some of the formatting for spoilers could be improved. It would be helpful to include an introduction for your example, since you can't just push enter two times like in normal text. But most of it is okay as is.